# How to remove a div which contains specific text by JQuery

Tags: jquery

I am trying to remove a div which contains    and space. it's not working please help

```
<div id="contentrow" class="contentrow_afterlhsrhs">
&nbsp;                  </div>
if($('.contentrow_afterlhsrhs').html() == "&nbsp;                   ") {
 $('.contentrow_afterlhsrhs').remove();
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/L8dwn/141/

Answer (score 1):

Here is the fiddle :

http://jsfiddle.net/L8dwn/143/

You can try it by removing space and adding space. This will remove your div only if there is the couple of `&nbsp;` and space inside your div.

```
<!-- This will not remove your div -->
<div id="contentrow" class="contentrow_afterlhsrhs">&nbsp;</div>
```

And

```
<!-- This will remove your div -->
<div id="contentrow" class="contentrow_afterlhsrhs">&nbsp;              </div>
```

Here is the JavaScript code :

```
var myContent = $('.contentrow_afterlhsrhs').html();
var trimContent = $.trim(myContent);
var contentWihoutNbsp = myContent.replace('&nbsp;','');

if( trimContent == "&nbsp;" && contentWihoutNbsp ){ 
    $('.contentrow_afterlhsrhs').remove();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use $.trim() function of jquery to remove unnecessary spaces from string. After fetching .html() of div trim the spaces and compare it with a string.

```
if($.trim($('.contentrow_afterlhsrhs').html()) == "&nbsp;") {
    $('.contentrow_afterlhsrhs').remove();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simpler approach:

```
$('.contentrow_afterlhsrhs:contains("\u00a0                     ")').remove();
```

(you have to use the unicode representation of `&nbsp;` for the contains() filter).

Edit: JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/L8dwn/144/

Answer (score 0):

Please check the working code below :

```js
console.log("Before Remove :" + $('.contentrow_afterlhsrhs').html());
if($.trim($('.contentrow_afterlhsrhs').html()) == "&nbsp;") {
  $('.contentrow_afterlhsrhs').remove();
}    
console.log("After Remove :" +$('.contentrow_afterlhsrhs').html());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="contentrow" class="contentrow_afterlhsrhs">
&nbsp;                  
</div>
```